# Passing Boolean State from one component to another component React.JS

Tags: reactjs, boolean, components

I want to pass Boolean State to change className from one component to another component. I tried to pass it through {this.props.isOpen}, but it did not work. How can I pass state value to another component?

Parent component

```
class Category extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state={ isOpen: false };
     this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

handleClick() {
this.setState({ isOpen : !this.state.isOpen })
}

render() {

const categoryContainer = this.state.isOpen ? "isopen" : "";
return(
<div>
<div className="categoryContainer">
    <h3>CATEGORIES</h3>
</div>
<button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click</button>
</div>
<div className={categoryStatus} id="category">
<input className="categoryInput" type="text" value="Add Category" placeholder="Add Category" /> 
    <ul>
    <li>Greetings</li>
    <li>Main Switchboard</li>
    <li>Interjections</li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 <Main isOpen={this.state.isOpen} />
 </div>
 )}
}
```

Child Component

```
class Main extends React.Component {

render() { 
const botStatus = !this.props.isOpen ? "isopen" : "";
const botInput = !this.props.isOpen ? "isopen" : "";
return (
<div>
<div className={botStatus} id="bot">
    <h2>MASTER INTENTS</h2>
    <input className={botInput} type="text" value="Add Intent" />

</div>
</div>);
}
}
```

Thank you for checking my question in advance.

Comment: I don't see where Category is consuming Main. You would normally do this by passing a prop to the Child from the Parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you want to pass a `prop` to a child component (`Main`) from your parent component (`Category`) you pass it in `render()` function as:

```
render(){
  <Main
   isOpen={this.state.isOpen}
  />
}
```

But i don't see you importing the child component (`Main`) at all or using it in the render function of your parent component (`Category`).

You need to use a child component in parent's render function in order to pass the `state` (and even `props`) of Parent component to its child component.

You can get more info from the [React Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html) as well.

> https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I want to make it work this part  `const botStatus = !this.state.isOpen ? "isopen" : "";
    const botInput = !this.state.isOpen ? "isopen" : "" ` by passing state from parent to child. I tried it with your solution but it didn't work. The value was not printed out in console  either..

Comment: Could you show the snippet from the part where you are `passing the prop from parent to the child component`  within the render function of `Category` component ? Or update the question and let us know. @ayumi

Comment: I added your snippet into 'Category' component which does not work yet..

Comment: In the end I integrated child component into parent component in order to make it work. I know it's not ideal solution.. Anyway thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

Per [React's Thinking](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) in React documentation, props are "a way of passing data from parent to child."

For your example, the **parent** component `Gallery` has to include the **child** component `Main` in the render function in order to make it works.

```
class Main extends Component {
    render() { 
      const botStatus = this.props.isOpen ? "isOpen" : "noOpen";  
      return (
      <div>
          <div>
            <h1>{botStatus}</h1>
          </div>
       </div>
      );
    }
  }

class Gallery extends Component {
  constructor() {
       super();
        this.state = {
        isOpen: false
        };
       }

  render() {
        return(
          <div>
            <div>

                <Main isOpen={this.state.isOpen}/>

            </div>
          </div>
        );
     }
  }
```